# Animate.css rotate3d issues between Safari and Chrome

Tags: css, google-chrome, safari, css-animations

I'm working on a project where I have a simple little rotate3d animation where these images will rotate 200deg clockwise and stop. The issue I'm having is that in Chrome they'll rotate clockwise, but then in Safari they'll rotate counter-clockwise...

Is there any way I can fix this? I tried specifying with -webkit- but that affects chrome AND safari.

Here's my code:

```css
.animated {
  animation-duration: 1s;
  animation-fill-mode: both;
}

.arrows {
  z-index: -99999;
}

.mid-nodes-wrapper:hover .arrows {
  animation-name: arrows;
}

@keyframes arrows {
  from {
    transform-origin: center;
    transform: rotate3d(0, 0, 1, 200deg);
    -webkit-transform: rotate3d(0, 0, 1, 200deg);
    z-index: -99999;
  }
  to {
    transform-origin: center;
    transform: none;
    -webkit-transform: none;
    z-index: -99999;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="mid-nodes-wrapper">
  <img class="animated arrows" src="http://pipsum.com/435x310.jpg" />
  </div
```

Sorry I can't share the page to show... unfortunately this is one of those projects with "secret" material.

EDIT: Adjusted code for better troubleshootiness

Comment: You might want to post the minimal HTML necessary to reproduce this problem in your question, perhaps using an image from http://pipsum.com/

Comment: Sorry about that. Edited.

Answer (score 0):

Some say Apple got rid of clocks in their offices for the sake of minimalism and this was the result. We'll probably never know.

In the meantime, we can use this workaround to get clockwise rotations:

```css
  0% {
-     transform: rotate3d(0, 0, 0, 0deg);
+     transform: rotate3d(0, 0, 0, 90deg);
  }

  100% {
-     transform: rotate3d(0, 0, 1, 360deg);
+     transform: rotate3d(0, 0, 4, 90deg);
  }
```

Use some pattern matching to generalize it to any rotation angle: the angle must be a multiple of an angle that is strictly less than 180deg (to resolve this ambiguity). For example, to get to 200deg, use 4 * 50deg (or 5 * 40deg, doesn't matter).